# JS gallery with hover to show large image - how to remove a hyperlink

Tags: jquery

I have a js gallery that when I hover over a thumbnail a large image shows on the page. However if I click the thumb it opens the large image in a new page.

Can anyone advise how I can remove the click function, and just keep the hover effect?

Here is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#thumbs ul li a').hover(
    function() {
      var currentBigImage = $('#bigpic img').attr('src');
      var newBigImage = $(this).attr('href');
      var currentThumbSrc = $(this).attr('rel');
      switchImage(newBigImage, currentBigImage, currentThumbSrc);
    },
    function() {}
  );
  function switchImage(imageHref, currentBigImage, currentThumbSrc) {
    var theBigImage = $('#bigpic img');
    if (imageHref != currentBigImage) {
      theBigImage.fadeOut(250, function(){
        theBigImage.attr('src', imageHref).fadeIn(250);
        var newImageDesc = $("#thumbs ul li a img[src='"+currentThumbSrc+"']")
          .attr('alt');
        $('p#desc').empty().html(newImageDesc);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

And my HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="thumbs">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a rel="http://..." href="http://...">
          <img src="http://..." alt="Ring 1" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a rel="http://..." href="http://...">
          <img src="http://..." alt="Ring 2" />
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a rel="http://..." href="http://...">
          <img src="http://..." alt="Ring 7" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a rel="http://..." href="http://...">
          <img src="http://..." alt="Ring 8" />
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="bigpic"><img src="http://..." alt="First Main Image" />
    <p id="desc">Move your mouse over the images on the left to view here...</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent the default action of clicking a hyperlink `<a>`, using [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault):

```
$('#thumbs ul li a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ub8GT/)**.

Answer (score 2):

try this out

```
$('#thumbs ul li a').click(function(){return false;});
```

Comment: You should be specific as it will apply on all anchor <a> tags in the document.

Comment: true... corrected. i sometimes tend to give partial answers to make guy/gal figure the rest out. my bad.

Comment: This also works great, thanks also. Now I just need to decide which one to use, this or the above..!

Comment: I think that `return false` is more safe than `preventDefault`, since it also prevent propagation. Then, **+1** for you!